# What is the domain of this function?

Tags: functions

Let $f(x)$ be the following function:

$$f(x)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x\cos t}}dt$$

How to find the domain of $f(x)$?

I know that we should have $$1+x\cos t>0,$$
then I start by saying if $t\in [0,\pi/2)\cup (3\pi/2,2\pi]$ then $\cos t>0$ and if $t\in (\pi/2,3\pi/2)$ then $\cos t<0$.

I cannot find the domain of $f(x)$ in formal way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good job with the formatting!

So if $x$ is fixed, then you need that for all $t$ in $[0,2\pi]$, $$x\cos t>-1$$
holds.
If $x = 0$, then this clearly holds.

If $x > 0$, then 
$$ \cos t > -\frac{1}{x}, \quad t \in [0,2\pi]$$
$\cos$ has it's minimum at $\pi$, where it is $-1$ so this is equivalent to 
$$ -1 > -\frac{1}{x}, \quad \text{or equivalently } \quad x < 1 $$

If $x < 0$, then 
$$ \cos t < -\frac{1}{x}, \quad t \in [0,2\pi]$$
$\cos$ has it's maximum at $0, 2\pi$ where it is $1$ so this is equivalent to 
$$ 1 < -\frac{1}{x}, \quad \text{or equivalently } \quad x > -1 $$
So we can conclude that the maximal possible domain of $f$ is the open interval $(-1,1).$